# What is concept of write files with bytes in java?

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I know that when I want to write a file, I should use code like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/myfile.jpg");

byte Data[] = new byte[1024];
long total = 0;

while ((count=inputStream.read(Data)) != -1) {
    total = total+count;
    outputStream.write(Data,0,count);
}
```

But I can't understand what happens with that result, is it writing an image file from zero to 100?

Can anyone describe for me how this occurred? Thanks

Comment: This appears to be an example of buffered input output.

Comment: You do need to close the streams after you're done...

Comment: i just want to know What factors cause to create a new file. i just want concept of write files.

Comment: plz take care i just want concept of write files. this code is sample and not really full code

Comment: Why don't you read the javadocs for the methods being called?

Comment: listen to hexafraction, if you are only worried about creating a file then this is a good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Could you review your choice of accepted answer ? The answer you have accepted is quite bad and is quite unlikely to help future readers, as it does not really answer the question completely. Thanks !

Answer (score -4, accepted):

That code would download a file from your URL and save it as /sdcard/myfile.jpg, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: People keep downvoting this.  I would delete it if I could, but it was the accepted answer so it doesn't let me.

Answer (score 8):

What this code does is to read 1024 bytes into a temporary buffer, write them to the output, and repeat, overwriting the contents of the buffer with the next data from the input, until there is no more data.

A bit of a breakdown of what the code does:

```
//get an InputStream from a URL, so we can download the data from it.
InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

//Create an OutputStream so we can write the data we get from URL to the file
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/myfile.jpg");

//create a temporary buffer to store the bytes we get from the URL
byte Data[] = new byte[1024];

long total = 0; //-< you don't actually use this anywhere..

//here, you read your InputStream (URL), into your temporary buffer, and you                                                
//also increment the count variable based on the number of bytes read.
//If there is no more data (read(...) returns -1) exit the loop, as we are finished.
while ((count=inputStream.read(Data)) != -1) {

    total = total+count;  //this is not actually used.. Also, where did you define "count" ?

    //write the content of the byte array "buffer" to the outputStream.
    //the "count" variable tells the outputStream how much you want to write.
    outputStream.write(Data,0,count);

   //After, do the whole thing again.
}
```

The interesting thing is the loop control statement:

```
while ((count=inputStream.read(Data)) != -1)
```

What is happening here is assignment *inside* the loop control statement. This is equivalent to this, just shorter:

```
count = inputStream.read(Data);
while(count != -1) {

 ...do something

 count = inputStream.read(Data);
}
```

Another thing here is `inputStream.read(Data)`. This reads the bytes into the temporary buffer (`Data`), and it *also* returns the number of bytes read, or `-1` if there are none left. This allows us to transfer data in an easy way, like here, by checking the return value of `read(...)` to control how data is written and to stop when there is none left.

---

Note that you should always *close* your `InputStream` and `OutputStream` when it is no longer needed, as you may end up with a corrupted or incomplete file otherwise. You can do so with the `.close()` method.

Answer (score 3):

> plz take care i just want concept of write files. this code is sample and not really full code

Let's start by examining non-buffered IO.

```
try (InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/myfile.jpg")) {
    int b;
    while ((b = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(b);
    }
}
```

This will read and write one byte at a time. Most physical devices support buffering (of one form or another). They can actually read multiple bytes in one pass (or transmit a packet of multiple bytes). In which case it's more efficient to read with a buffer (remembering to `close` in a `finally` block, or use a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

**tl;dr**

Non-Buffered IO reads one byte at a time (for one-megabyte that would be one million calls to read). Buffered IO reads multiple bytes as a *block* to optimize, or reduce, the `read`(s).

Comment: then , As i understand, With each iteration of the loop , amount of 1024 bytes of image file , write to my new file until input file have'nt any bytes. thanks

Comment: @SadeqShajary Yes, specifically `count` is the number of bytes read in each iteration and it will be between `-1` and `1024` per iteration (with `-1` being end of file).